# How to test a FileField in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have this serializer which I am trying to test:

```
class AttachmentSerializer(CustomModelSerializer):
    order = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    file = FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Attachment
        fields = (
            'id',
            'order',
            'name',
            'file_type',
            'file',
            'created_at',
        )
```

My test simply checks whether it is valid or not:

```
    def test_serializer_create(self):
        self.data = {
            'order': self.order.pk,
            'name': 'sample_name',
            'file_type': 'image',
            'created_at': datetime.now(),
            'file': open(self.image_path, 'rb').read()
        }

        serializer = AttachmentSerializer(data=self.data)

        self.assertTrue(serializer.is_valid())
```

And I am constantly getting this error:

```
{'file': ['No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.']}
```

I tried to create a file in a number of different ways, such as with StringIO/BytesIO, File and etc. to no avail.

What might be wrong?

Comment: You should read this http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#file-upload-fields. Your data needs to be parsed properly

Answer (score 4):

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
content = SimpleUploadedFile("file.txt", "filecontentstring")
data = {'content': content}
```

try smth like that , because if you check FileField serializer's code - it expects UploadedFile that should have name and size:

```
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
    try:
        # `UploadedFile` objects should have name and size attributes.
        file_name = data.name
        file_size = data.size
    except AttributeError:
        self.fail('invalid')
```

and StringIO or opened file objects doesn't have size attribute.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 100 times

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. It turned out that Django REST Framework FileField cannot be used with a JSON API parser. DRF [documentation states](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#file-upload-fields) that "Most parsers, such as e.g. JSON don't support file uploads."

Your question does not show which parser you configured, but given how common JSON is, it may be the culprit. You can set a different parser either across the board, or for a specific API view, as described [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/).

Once the parser problem was fixed, I made the test work with a Django File, but perhaps other approaches could work too:

```
from django.core.files import File

def test_create(self):
    ...
    data = {
        'file': File(open(path_to_test_file, 'rb')),
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you pass an opened file to the APIClient / APIRequestFactory, not to the view itself. The Django request will wraps the file to an [`UploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/files/uploads/#uploaded-files) which is what you should use.

Comment: I tried to use SimpleUploadedFile, but got another error: `'non_field_errors': ['Invalid data']`

Comment: Not sure about that one, files won't come with regular dictionaries and it's likely the view expects a different structure. You might want to look at the DRF's request source.